# How can I integrate Hadoop with Mahout?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

How can I integrate **Hadoop** with ***Mahou*t** ?
i want to *perform data Analytics* and need to have machine learning libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by reviewing the mahout site, reviewing the tutorials, there are lots of useful links http://mahout.apache.org

There are a number of different books out there that will take you from first principles to producing Data Analytics, this is probably a good place to start (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033400.do) if you know python.